# Image slider requiring 1 extra click to reset. Unable to fix

Tags: javascript

I've tried to fix this problem for the past 1 hour without success. Basically, once I reach "imageB", I have to click 1 extra time before the image resets back to "imageA". I don't understand why this is happening. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated:

```
HTML:

<body>
    <div class="main-container">
      <div class="image-div">
        <img width="500px" id="image-holder" src="images/imageA.jpeg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <button onclick="nextImage()">Next</button>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>

JS:

let imageHolder = document.getElementById("image-holder");

let images = ["images/imageA.jpeg", "images/imageB.jpeg"];
let i = 1;

function nextImage() {
  if (i < images.length) {
    imageHolder.setAttribute("src", images[i]);
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a code which can solve your problem, but I think it's a little long, maybe you can find a code more readable on more short than my, anyway here is my solution and it works for me:

everytime when you click in the button, the function give the next item in the array (next source), but if the item is in the end of the array he start again by the first item in the array.

```
   <div class="main-container">
    <div class="image-div">
     <img width="500px" id="image-holder" src="./img1.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <button onclick="nextImage()">Next</button>
   </div>
```

```
    let imageHolder = document.getElementById("image-holder");

    let images = ["./img1.png", "./oz.png","./img2.png"];

    function nextImage() {
      let getSrcAttr = imageHolder.getAttribute("src");
      let newSrc = 
      imageHolder.setAttribute("src",images[(images.indexOf(getSrcAttr))+1]);
      if(images.indexOf(getSrcAttr) == (images.length)-1){
         newSrc = imageHolder.setAttribute("src",images[0]);
      }
    }
```

Comment: That actually solved my problem! Do you mind explaining this part to me: 

" imageHolder.setAttribute("src",images[(images.indexOf(getSrcAttr))+1]);
      if(images.indexOf(getSrcAttr) == (images.length)-1){
         newSrc = imageHolder.setAttribute("src",images[0]);"

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Okay, first, we need to get the current ` src `, we have this source in our array, so we can get next item in this array if we use arr[(arr.indexOf(item)+1)], and then we get the next item in the array, then we put it in the src of the image, the I used setAttribute to change the current src but the next src (the current src in array buy the next src in the array) ....... but if the item in the end of the array we can't get then next item, then we need to start from the beginning of the array.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand the code completely now. Thank you once again.